# ssh with for loop - parentheses problem

Tags: bash, control-flow

I have the following script:

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]
do
case "$1" in
    -h) HOST="$2"; shift 2;;
esac
done

if test -z "$HOST"
then
    [...]
else
    TODAY=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') 
    configs=("/etc/inittab" "/etc/default/cron" "/etc/default/login" "/etc/default/su" "/etc/group" "/etc/inet/inetd.conf" "/etc/mnttab" "/etc/netmasks" "/etc/nsswitch.conf" "/etc/protocols" "/etc/services" "/etc/syslog.conf" "/var/sadm/install/contents" "/etc/user_attr" "/etc/passwd")  
    ssh $HOST 
    for (i=0; i<${#configs[*]}; i++) 
    do 
        digest -v -a md5 ${configs[$i]} | awk '{print $2,$4}' | sed 's/) (/\n/;s/[()]//g'; 
    done > /tmp/md5_config_$TODAY.txt
fi
```

If I execute the script with a hostname (scriptname.sh -h hostname) I get the error

```
line 97: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 97: `for (i=0;i<${#configs[*]};i++;); '
```

Is there a way to solve it? I want to execute the "digest" command on the remote host with the filenames of the array "configs"

Edit: Actual state

```
else
    TODAY=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') 
    configs=("/etc/inittab" "/etc/default/cron" "/etc/default/login" "/etc/default/su" "/etc/group" "/etc/inet/inetd.conf" "/etc/mnttab" "/etc/netmasks" "/etc/nsswitch.conf" "/etc/protocols" "/etc/services" "/etc/syslog.conf" "/var/sadm/install/contents" "/etc/user_attr" "/etc/passwd")  
    ssh $HOST 
    for ((i=0; i<${#configs[*]}; i++)) 
    do 
        digest -v -a md5 ${configs[$i]} | awk '{print $2,$4}' | sed 's/) (/\n/;s/[()]//g'; 
    done > /tmp/md5_config_$TODAY.txt
fi
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon near the `i++` in the line 97.

Comment: I removed it (Code: for (i=0;i<${#configs[*]};i++); ) but still got the same error

Comment: Avinash means : remove the `;` **at the end** of the line `for(i=0.....)`

Comment: The bash for loop has a very specific syntax. You need double parentheses around it, semicolons *between* the three expressions but *not* after the last, and also *no* semicolon after the closing parenthesis. Both of your loops contain syntax errors. Is this really the script, or did you type it in manually?

Comment: Thank you @OlivierDulac. Now i got the little problem that the ssh command is working but i end up on bash of remote host without execution of the lines which follow the "ssh $HOST" command

Comment: @KilianFoth The error was in the script. I did a correction and now the error with the parentheses is solved. But I got another problem, as described under your first comment

Comment: I don't know about your specific versions, but my bash would execute `ssh $HOST` and then wait for ssh to terminate before continuing with the for loop ...

Comment: And that's the point. I want to execute the for loop on remote host. I mean: 1. ssh to remote host 2. execute loop on remote host 3. terminate ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to write such a thing I would

```
TODAY=`date --iso`
CONFIGS="/etc/inittab /etc/default/cron /etc/default/login ..."

ssh -q $HOST 'for cfg in '${CONFIGS}'; do digest -v -a md5 ${cfg}; done' |\
    awk '{print $2,$4}' | sed 's/) (/\n/;s/[()]//g' >> /tmp/md5_config_$TODAY.txt
```

However, you might want to check out [Tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) and other tools, which are made for such purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Bananguin. The script works as it should